# why is it std::thread threadObj((WorkerThread())) instead of std::thread threadObj(WorkerThread()())

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm confused with a thread test.
The code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
class WorkerThread{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout<<"Worker Thread "<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" is Executing"<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::thread threadObj((WorkerThread())); //confused line
    threadObj.join();
    std::cout<<"Exiting from Main Thread"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it std::thread threadObj((WorkerThread())) instead of std::thread threadObj(WorkerThread()())? Thanks a lot!

The output is:

```
Worker Thread 139661803513600 is Executing
Exiting from Main Thread
```

Comment: Side note: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` used along side `#include <thread>` suggests that you don't know what  `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is used for. [Don't fall victim to a Cargo Cult.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) Make sure you know what you are using and why.

Comment: My fault, there is no need for `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` here.

Comment: sorry,  slip of a pen,there is no need for #include <thread> here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator()` is just a name with a funky spelling.
If you rename it to something "un-magical", like "call_as_function", you would get

```
class WorkerThread{
public:
    void call_as_function()
    {
        std::cout<<"Worker Thread "<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" is Executing"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::thread threadObj(WorkerThread().call_as_function()); 
    threadObj.join();
    std::cout<<"Exiting from Main Thread"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

where you probably see that it is wrong - you want to pass an instance of `WorkerThread`, not the result of calling a member function of an instance of `WorkerThread`.

The reason for the extra pair of parentheses in the working case - that you need

```
std::thread threadObj((WorkerThread()))
```

rather than

```
std::thread threadObj(WorkerThread())
```

is that without them you get a declaration of a function.

You might have seen something like this,

```
request for member ‘join’ in ‘threadObj’, which is of non-class type ‘std::thread(WorkerThread (*)())’
```

which says that `threadObj` is a function that takes a pointer to a parameter-less function that returns a `WorkerThread`, and returns a `std::thread`.

Enter "most vexing parse" in a search engine of your choice for the details.

Comment: Thank you, but when we use the extra pair of parentheses, how the threadObj locate the operator() function?

Comment: @tingdazhuang I've clarified which "extra pair" I referred to. They have nothing to do with `operator()`.

Comment: The output mean the `operator()` function in `WorkerThread` is called, if the "extra pair" has nothing to do with `operator()`, how does the `threadObj` locate the `operator()`?

Comment: The thread instance doesn't do that; it just uses a normal function call - `object()` - and the compiler can translate that to `object.operator()()` since it knows that your class has such a member.

Comment: As your example, if we modify the `operator()` to `call_as_function`, there is no way to compile success unless we define an instance of `WorkerThread` and call the `call_as_function` by `std::thread threadObj(&WorkerThread::call_as_function, &instance)`.  I don't know why 'operator()' has this privilege that doesn't need to define an instance.

Comment: @tingdazhuang `WorkerThread()` creates an instance and `std::thread` has a constructor template that can take any callable object. Defining `operator()` makes a `WorkerThread` instance a callable object. (It works in the same way as `WorkerThread worker; worker();`. If you don't understand how that works, look for the relevant section in your favourite C++ book.)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I think i get it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `std::thread` requires a callable and `WorkerThread()()` gives result of calling `WorkerThread::operator()`, so there won't be any matching constructor with `WorkerThread()()`

If you wanted to ask why not use `threadObj(WorkerThread())`, its because of `most vexing parse`, compile treat `std::thread threadObj(WorkerThread())` as function declaration, you can read more about it here [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)